# Rails 3 routing not generating proper paths for new vs edit views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, routes

I'm getting some funkiness that is absolutely confounding me with Rails 3. I can't seem to get the routing to generate the proper path using the (mostly) standard _form style of the scaffold.

First off, I'm doing everything within an "admin" namespace. I'm finding that the form partial throws a routing error if I use admin_team_path(@team) to generate the path when creating a new Team, but then submitting the form when editing, it throws an error unless I use admin_teams_path.

admin_team_path(@team) where @team = Team.new throws this error:

No route matches {:controller=>"admin/teams", :action=>"show", :id=>#}

Meanwhile...
admin_teams_path(@team) where @team =  throws this error:

The action 'edit' could not be found for TeamsController

In the latter case, it seems to be directing to the URL: http://localhost:3000/teams/1/edit - it's not recognizing the namespace properly.

Here's my full _form.html:

```
<%= semantic_form_for(@team, :url => admin_teams_path(@team)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.semantic_errors %>

  <%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :user_id %>
    <%= f.input :league_id %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.buttons do %>
   <%= f.commit_button :button_html =>{:class => "primary"} %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

What gives? What's the right way to create this form partial so it works for both new and edit actions?

Namespaces seem to be such a mess to work with.

Comment: How are your routes defined ? sth like this namespace :admin do resources :teams end ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you have defined your routes in a RESOURCEful manner, like so:

```
namespace :admin do
    resources :teams
end
```

Then, in your _form partial you can let rails take care of the action like so:

```
<%= semantic_form_for(["admin", @team]) do |f| %>
    .... #rest of the code
<% end %>
```